# Transposing multiple rows with custom columns in SAS

Tags: sas, multiple-columns, transpose

[Data in present state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPyuy.jpg)

I need to transpose in such a way that :

[Data should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diunJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you put the "present state" data in your question as text/data that we can cut and paste into a program.  I think this is simple transpose with ID but I don't want to type in your data.

Comment: This is not a valid SO question in its current state.  Information should be in the question, not in links or pictures.  Beyond that, this is a code request and also not on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I typed it in.  This uses features of the TRANSPOSE procedure PREFIX and  ID.  It also requires options validvarname=any; to get the equal sign in the names.

```
data mh;
   input subject $ mhgcat_cod mhgdtn_raw :date. mhgrslt_raw;
   format mhgdtn_raw date9.;
   cards;
00031001 4  06mar2012 12.7
00031001 6  06mar2012 90.2
00031001 11 06mar2012 48.1
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose out=flat prefix='MHGCAT_COD='n;
   by subject mhgdtn_raw;
   id mhgcat_cod;
   var mhgrslt_raw;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for not putting it in required format. This is exactly what I wanted. Super awesome. Thanks!